# Image decompression: Reconstructed LZW dictionary somewhat, not exactly matches original dictionary

Tags: disassembly, decompress, graphics

I am attempting to reverse an animation format that uses (I think) some form of LZW for each of the frames.

I have determined that a 12-bit code is used throughout the image. Here is a short target image with the code words separated out:

```
[0x0ff, 0x100, 0x101, 0x102, 0x103, 0x104, 0x104, 0x02f, 0x106, 0x02f, 0x105, 0x108, 0x109, 0x10a, 0x10b, 0x107, 0x10c, 0x106, 0x10b, 0x10e, 0x10f, 0x103, 0x10d, 0x111, 0x02f, 0x110, 0x113, 0x109, 0x112, 0x01c, 0x116, 0x01c, 0x10c, 0x114, 0x119, 0x100, 0x111, 0x117, 0x11c, 0x118, 0x107, 0x11a, 0x110, 0x11b, 0x11c, 0x01d, 0x122, 0x116, 0x10c, 0x11f, 0x10b, 0x120, 0x117, 0x122, 0x128, 0x117, 0x107, 0x125, 0x108, 0x126, 0x116, 0x128, 0x123, 0x11c, 0x107, 0x12b, 0x103, 0x12c, 0x01c, 0x12e, 0x01d, 0x11d, 0x124, 0x106, 0x131, 0x100, 0x132, 0x134, 0x136, 0x137, 0x106, 0x131, 0x139, 0x12e, 0x13b, 0x12a, 0x107, 0x125, 0x13d, 0x129, 0x13f, 0x13c, 0x02f, 0x11f, 0x141, 0x12f, 0x143, 0x13c, 0x105, 0x112, 0x103, 0x10d, 0x11d, 0x13a, 0x147, 0x130, 0x107, 0x102, 0x112, 0x107, 0x102, 0x10c, 0x01b, 0x121, 0x142, 0x14b, 0x14c, 0x14d, 0x154, 0x100, 0x14e, 0x14f, 0x152, 0x157, 0x154, 0x106, 0x153, 0x02f, 0x0ff, 0x107, 0x01b, 0x15d, 0x156, 0x157, 0x14b, 0x14d, 0x13b, 0x107, 0x0ff, 0x107, 0x01c, 0x15e, 0x160, 0x167, 0x13b, 0x13e, 0x11e, 0x10c, 0x116, 0x166, 0x168, 0x168, 0x134, 0x123, 0x115, 0x15e, 0x15f, 0x16f, 0x170, 0x172, 0x106, 0x0ff, 0x164, 0x165, 0x16e, 0x176, 0x17c, 0x107, 0x0ff, 0x16c, 0x17a, 0x15d, 0x17c, 0x17d, 0x106, 0x100, 0x17e, 0x174, 0x181, 0x16f, 0x107, 0x101, 0x183, 0x17b, 0x157, 0x180, 0x186, 0x106, 0x102, 0x187, 0x18a, 0x152, 0x174, 0x175, 0x152, 0x107, 0x103, 0x18c, 0x190, 0x13b, 0x18f, 0x188, 0x147, 0x107, 0x104, 0x192, 0x147, 0x17b, 0x18f, 0x14b, 0x01b, 0x107, 0x105, 0x198, 0x194, 0x180, 0x179, 0x195, 0x19f, 0x106, 0x109, 0x192, 0x175, 0x184, 0x126, 0x1a2, 0x16d, 0x15d, 0x106, 0x10a, 0x1a4, 0x1a2, 0x107, 0x0ff, 0x120, 0x195, 0x15e, 0x107, 0x10b, 0x1ab, 0x1a6, 0x106, 0x101, 0x1ad, 0x195, 0x107, 0x10e, 0x1b0, 0x14f, 0x107, 0x104, 0x1b2, 0x1a0, 0x106, 0x10f, 0x1b0, 0x16b, 0x108, 0x12c, 0x107, 0x113, 0x1a4, 0x16b, 0x02f, 0x10a, 0x159, 0x02f, 0x114, 0x18c, 0x13c, 0x10f, 0x14d, 0x11a, 0x148, 0x140, 0x106, 0x113, 0x10c, 0x12b, 0x1bc, 0x138, 0x11f, 0x154, 0x1c0, 0x12b, 0x10d, 0x1c1, 0x101, 0x1c4]
```

Based on the understanding I gained from [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Image_decoding) and [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lzw-lempel-ziv-welch-compression-technique/), I wrote the following decoder for just the compressed image stream:

```
#!/bin/python3

import bitstring

def decompress_frame(data):
    compressed_stream = bitstring.ConstBitStream(data)
    bitmap_stream = []

    # INITIALIZE THE CODEBOOK.
    # The codebook should be initailized to the literal values 0x00 to 0xff in index order.
    code_book = []
    for initial_code in range(0x000, 0x100):
        code_book.append([initial_code])

    # DECODE THE FIRST PIXEL.
    # A 12-bit code is used throughout the image - no larger, no smaller.
    CODE_LENGTH: int = 12
    # The first pixel is always interpreted as a literal pixel.
    code_word = compressed_stream.read(CODE_LENGTH).uint
    bitmap_stream.append(code_word)
    previous_code_word = code_word
    while True:
        # READ THE NEXT CODE WORD.
        try:
            code_word = compressed_stream.read(CODE_LENGTH).uint
        except bitstring.ReadError:
            print("Out of bits")
            break

        # CHECK IF THE CODE WORD IS IN THE CODEBOOK.
        code_word_in_code_book = code_word < len(code_book)
        if code_word_in_code_book:
            # WRITE THE LITERAL PIXELS FOR THIS CODE WORD.
            literal_pixels = code_book[code_word]
            bitmap_stream.extend(literal_pixels)

            # ADD THE NEXT CODE TO THE CODEBOOK.
            # When the code word is already in the codebook, the next code is formed by 
            # the previous code word and the first pixel of this code word.
            previous_code_word_pixels = code_book[previous_code_word]
            code_word_first_pixel = [code_book[code_word][0]]
            code_string = previous_code_word_pixels + code_word_first_pixel
            code_book.extend([code_string])
        else:
            # ADD THE NEXT CODE TO THE CODEBOOK.
            # When the code word is not in the codebook, add a code word formed by
            # the literal pixel string for the previous code word followed by the first 
            # literal pixel for the previous code word.
            previous_code_word_pixels = []
            previous_code_word_pixels = code_book[previous_code_word]
            previous_code_word_first_pixel = [code_book[previous_code_word][0]]
            code_string = previous_code_word_pixels + previous_code_word_first_pixel
            code_book.extend([code_string])

            # WRITE THE LITERAL PIXELS FOR THE ADDED CODE WORD.
            bitmap_stream.extend(code_string)

        previous_code_word = code_word

    return code_book, bytes(bitmap_stream)

with open('Frame0', 'rb') as sample_file:
    code_book, uncompressed_image = decompress_frame(sample_file.read())
    for index, entry in enumerate(code_book):
        print(f'{index:03x}: {entry}')
```

From the first added entry (entry 0x100), here's the beginning of the emitted codebook:

```
0x100: [255, 255],
0x101: [255, 255, 255],
0x102: [255, 255, 255, 255],
0x103: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
0x104: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
0x105: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
0x106: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 47],
0x107: [47, 255],
0x108: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 47, 47],
0x109: [47, 255],
0x10A: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
0x10B: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 47, 47, 47],
0x10C: [47, 255, 255]
```

(Full attempted codebook at https://pastebin.com/hWBsxdTE .)

However, starting at 0x106, the rebuilt codebook gets off track and never gets back on again. When I do a pixdump of the emitted pixels, I see nothing recognizable. However, by some breakpointing in OllyDbg, I extracted the correct codebook from memory for this same frame. Here is the start of the *correct* codebook, as extracted from memory and verified to decompress the image correctly:

```
0x100: [255, 255],
0x101: [255, 255, 255],
0x102: [255, 255, 255, 255],
0x103: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
0x104: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
0x105: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
0x106: [47, 47],
0x107: [47, 47, 47],
0x108: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
0x109: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
0x10A: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
0x10B: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
0x10C: [47, 47, 47, 47]
```

(Full dumped codebook at https://pastebin.com/x7V0VmkY .)

The structure of the dumped (correct) codebook suggested to me that maybe some sort of hashing was going on, but I do not see hashing logic in the disassembly. (My disassembly skills aren't super strong so I could have missed it.) There are no debugging symbols or helpful strings that I can find.

Any thoughts on what my decoder script could be missing here that would cause a malformed codebook and thus incorrectly decoded image?

For the example frame discussed above, this is the correct image (taken as a screenshot from the animation):

[image: ARROW.ATR, Frame 0]